# Unable to debug 401 Unauthorized error in .Net 6 Web API

Tags: c#, webapi, unauthorized

The custom Authorization has been used in this code from a referenced library..
It's working and getting 200 OK when I run the code over visual studio and invoke from postman but when I deploy getting 401 unauthorized.. Seems to be a config issue but to getting any details other than 401, I'm struggling to do debug, is there a way in .net we can write some code that should capture the reason why we are getting the 401..  In my case the code is not even hitting break point in case of 401 issue, because this custom authorization filter is been executed before the action call, so not so sure what to do to get the actual cause for this problem..

Comment: 401 may be thrown by some proxy even before the request reaches the Asp.Net Core. If you are sure that your Asp.Net Core application throws it, try to increase the logging level of requests to "Information" and check the logs. [There](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) you may find information about how to increase the logging level

Comment: hi GoodBoy, thanks for your response, I tried this but no luck.

Comment: not much to debug, 401 is unauthorized, your authentication flow is not working

Comment: thanks everyone, yes now this is resolved.. Actually during authentication there was a logic written in the code to compare two URLs, there was a mismatchbetween the  URLs which caused the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try using ShowPII

```
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved, the cause was there was some data mismatch in the token validation, after adding enough logs into the code we were able to identify the cause and fixed the problem